# Using Median Function with sort and Array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate the Median of an array. I was able to get the MIN, MAX, AVG, But I am having difficulty with the Median and the way the display sorts the information.

My Question is How do I get the Median, using a function individually for each status. (Status being A, C, E, L, P, W)

My Code is:

```
<?php
echo "<p><b>A</b> = Active, <b>E</b> = Expired, <b>L</b> = Canceled, <b>P</b> = Pending, <b>W</b> = Withdrawn</p>\n";
// COUNT STATUS
include '_inc/include.php';
$query = "SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM median GROUP BY status"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(status)'] ." ". $row['status'] ." items.";
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

The display is:

A = Active, C = Closed, E = Expired, L = Canceled, P = Pending, W = Withdrawn

There are 6 A items

There are 2 C items

There are 9 E items

There are 4 L items

There are 2 P items

My Code is:

```
$query = "SELECT listprice, status, MIN(listprice), COUNT(status) FROM median GROUP BY status"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "The MIN list price for the  ". $row['COUNT(status)'] ." ". $row['status'] ." is $" .    $row['MIN(listprice)'];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

The display is:

The MIN list price for the 6 A is $139900.00

The MIN list price for the 2 C is $149900.00

The MIN list price for the 9 E is $138000.00

The MIN list price for the 4 L is $229000.00

The MIN list price for the 2 P is $179000.00

The MAX and AVG is similar to the above.

I tried to include a function to calculate the Median (MED)

```
<?php
function median($arr)
{
sort($arr);
$count = count($arr); //count the number of values in array
$middleval = floor(($count-1)/2); // find the middle value, or the lowest middle value
if ($count % 2) { // odd number, middle is the median
    $median = $arr[$middleval];
} else { // even number, calculate avg of 2 medians
    $low = $arr[$middleval];
    $high = $arr[$middleval+1];
    $median = (($low+$high)/2);
}
return $median;
}

echo median(array($lp)) . "\n";  // 153500
echo "<p> </p>";
echo median(array(4.1, 7.2, 1.7, 9.3, 4.4, 3.2)) . "\n";       // 4.25

?>
```

This works for a static array, but how do I calculate it to look like the above MIN, MAX?

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$ld=mysql_result($result,$i,"listdate");
$cd=mysql_result($result,$i,"closedate");
$contractd=mysql_result($result,$i,"contractdate");
$s=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");
$scd=mysql_result($result,$i,"statuschangedate");
$wd=mysql_result($result,$i,"withdrawdate");
$cand=mysql_result($result,$i,"canceldate");
$lp=mysql_result($result,$i, "listprice");
$sp=mysql_result($result,$i,"soldprice");
$gla=mysql_result($result,$i,"gla");
$b=mysql_result($result,$i,"built");
$o=mysql_result($result,$i,"owner");
$fs=mysql_result($result,$i,"fore");
$ss=mysql_result($result,$i,"shortsale");
$f=mysql_result($result,$i,"features");
?>
```

I think maybe the reason I having so much trouble with this is that the data in the table is uploaded via file upload (csv). But I didn't think that really had anything to do with it because the data is already there.

I used $lp for listprice in place of the static array in the median function, that is were it goes blank.

Answer (score 1):

> ...that is where it goes blank.

Blank pages are an indicator of an PHP error being thrown but having error display settings turned off. Make sure you [turn on error reporting](http://www.jorble.com/2012/06/how-to-display-php-error/) to see the issue.

One thing of importance, the deprecated `mysql_result()` function will retrieve the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set. If you were hoping to have multiple values by passing your median function `array($lp)` it's not going to happen that way. Additionally, if the `mysql_result()` function fails or doesn't find a result, it returns false mean the array you pass to your median function is now `array(false)`.

Those are some things to keep in mind while troubleshooting. Turn on error reporting and the problem should be much easier to deduce.

Comment: blank meaning there is no error the result is $0, when I use $lp i get one value of 179000, but I am not sure what it is doing

Answer (score 0):

There is no `median` function for most MySQL versions. However, MariaDB 10.3.3 just introduced a [median function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/median/).